# How to send selected values with ajax to controller to use as parameters in stored procedure

Tags: ajax, stored-procedures, multi-select, sqlcommand

I am trying to collect selected values from two drop down boxes with multiselect. Then send the data with ajax as strings to a controller to use in stored procedure for a partial view. I can see that the strings are being sent, but the SQL is not running. Can anyone help please, I have trawled everywhere but can't find a similar problem. Thank you.

## VIEW

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="PropLandingGrid">
    <div class="PLAND_A1">
        <select name="SuburbDDL" id="SuburbDDL" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="PLAND_A3">
        <select name="AreaDDL" id="AreaDDL" multiple="multiple"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="PLAND_D1"><button type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn-det15035">Show</button></div>
</div>

<div id="PropContainer"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var SuburbDDL = $('#SuburbDDL');
    var AreaDDL = $('#AreaDDL');
    var AreaDet = null;
    var AreaQ = null;
    var SuburbDet = 1;
    var SuburbQ = null;

    AreaDDL.multipleSelect();

    // suburb
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tProps/GetSuburbList',
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            SuburbDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: "Select Suburb" }));

            $(data).each(function (PropLanding2, item) {
                SuburbDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: item.SuburbID, text: item.Suburb }));
            });

            $('select option:contains("Hout Bay")').prop('selected', true);

            SuburbDDL.multipleSelect();
            SuburbDet = 1;
        }
    });
    // area
    $.ajax({
        url: '/tProps/GetAreaListJS',
        method: 'post',
        data: { SuburbID: '1' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            AreaDDL.empty();
            AreaDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: "Select Area" }));
            AreaDDL.attr("disabled", false);

            $(data).each(function (PropLanding2, item) {
                AreaDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: item.AreaID, text: item.Area }));
            });

            AreaDDL.multipleSelect();
            AreaDet = null;
        }
    });

    SuburbDDL.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '-1') {
            AreaDDL.empty();
            AreaDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: "Select Area" }));
            AreaDDL.val('-1');
            AreaDDL.attr('disabled', true);
        }
        else {

            AreaDDL.attr("disabled", false);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/tProps/GetAreaListJS',
                method: 'post',
                data: { SuburbID: $(this).val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                    AreaDDL.empty();
                    AreaDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: -1, text: "Select Area" }));
                    AreaDDL.attr("disabled", false);

                    $(data).each(function (PropLanding2, item) {
                        AreaDDL.append($('<option/>', { value: item.AreaID, text: item.Area }));
                    });
                }

            });

            SuburbDet = SuburbDDL.multipleSelect('getSelects');
        }

    });

    AreaDDL.change(function ()
    {
        if ($(this).val() == '-1') {
            AreaDet = null;
        }
        else
        {
            AreaDet = AreaDDL.multipleSelect('getSelects');
        }
    });


    $("#btnDets").click(function () {

            alert("Suburb: " + SuburbDet + ", Area: " + AreaDet)
        });

    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {

            SuburbDet1 = (String(SuburbDet).replace(/,/g, "</SuburbId></Detail><Detail><SuburbId>"));
            SuburbDet2 = "<Root><Detail><SuburbId>" + SuburbDet1 + "</SuburbId></Detail></Root>"
            console.log(SuburbDet2);

            AreaDet1 = (String(AreaDet).replace(/,/g, "</AreaId></Detail><Detail><AreaId>"));
            AreaDet2 = "<Root><Detail><AreaId>" + AreaDet1 + "</AreaId></Detail></Root>"
            console.log(AreaDet2);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/tProps/p_PropList2',
                contentType: 'application/html',
                type: 'GET',
                data:
                  {
                    'SuburbData': SuburbDet2, 'AreaData': AreaDet2
                  },

                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#PropContainer').html(result);
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("something went wrong");

                }
            })

        });
```

## CONTROLLER

```
    public PartialViewResult p_PropList2(String SuburbData, String AreaData, string sortBy)

    {

        String StringSQL = "DECLARE @SuburbXML VARCHAR(MAX) DECLARE @AreaXML VARCHAR(MAX) SET @SuburbXML = " + SuburbData + " SET @AreaXML = " + AreaData + " EXEC spPropertyListXML @SuburbXML, @AreaXML";
        var datta = db.Database.SqlQuery<spPropertyListXML_Result>(StringSQL).ToList();
        return PartialView("p_PropList2", datta.ToList());
    }
```

## STORED PROCEDURE

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPropertyListXML]
       @SuburbXML                                       XML     -- sd1: defined as xml
     , @AreaXML                                         XML     -- sd1: defined as xml

AS
BEGIN
SET FMTONLY OFF

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRY
```

---

### --      create temp

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempSuburb                        (SuburbId       INT)
    CREATE TABLE #TempArea                          (AreaId         INT)
```

---

### --      load temp

```
    INSERT INTO #TempSuburb(SUburbId)
    SELECT Suburb.ID.query('SuburbId').value('.','INT') 
    FROM @SuburbXML.nodes('/Root/Detail') AS Suburb(ID)

    INSERT INTO #TempArea(AreaId)
    SELECT Area.ID.query('AreaId').value('.','INT') 
    FROM @AreaXML.nodes('/Root/Detail') AS Area(ID)
```

---

### --      use data in temp

```
    SELECT tArea.Area, tArea.AreaID, tSuburb.SuburbID, tSuburb.Suburb, tProp.Erf, tProp.ErfSq, tProp.Num
    FROM tprop
    INNER JOIN tArea ON tArea.AreaID = tprop.area
    INNER JOIN tSuburb ON tSuburb.SuburbID = tarea.SuburbID
    WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #TempSuburb)
          OR tSuburb.SuburbID IN (SELECT a.SuburbId FROM #TempSuburb a)
          )
     AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #TempArea)
          OR tArea.AreaID IN (SELECT a.AreaId FROM #TempArea a)
          )
```

---

### --      drop temp

```
    DROP TABLE #TempSuburb
    DROP TABLE #TempArea

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT >  0 ROLLBACK TRAN

    DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE          VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY         INT

    SELECT @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE()
         , @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY()

    RAISERROR(@ERROR_MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, 1)
END CATCH
```

END